# How to disable each button if it is clicked and should remain inactive so that the user does not click the same button any more in android?

Tags: android, button

I'm new to android and want your help.

I have got five buttons in an activity. Each button leading to different activities. On clicking each button, we are lead to an activity where I do database insertion functions and on returning the user is lead to the main activity where the five buttons remain.

Now, what I want is I want the user to know which button he already clicked so as to avoid the user's confusion. That is I want to disable the button after he is done with the insertions in the activities lead by each of the button.

This is what I tried:

```
public class ResourcesActivity extends Activity {
    static boolean isBtnVenueClikced = false; {


        public void buttonListeners() {
            venue_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    isBtnVenueClikced = true;
                    Log.i("In button venue click isBtnVenueClikced ", isBtnVenueClikced + "");
                    Intent venue_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VenueActivity.class);
                    venue_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(venue_intent);

                }


            });
            food_cost_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("In Food Button isBtnVenueClikced ", isBtnVenueClikced + "");
                    //isBtnFoodClicked = true;
                    Intent food_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FoodAndBeveragesActivity.class);
                    food_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(food_intent);

                }
            });
            accomodation_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    //isBtnAccClicked = true;
                    Intent accomodation_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccomodationActivity.class);
                    accomodation_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(accomodation_intent);

                }
            });
            guest_details_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    //isBtnGuestClicked = true;
                    Intent guest_details_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GuestDetailsActivity.class);
                    guest_details_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(guest_details_intent);

                }
            });
            miscl_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    //isBtnOtheClicked = true;
                    Intent others_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OthersActivity.class);
                    others_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(others_intent);

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();
            Log.i("In onResume isBtnVenueClikced ", isBtnVenueClikced + "");
            //checkcliks();
            //isBtnVenueClikced = false;
            if (isBtnVenueClikced == false) {
                venue_btn.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                venue_btn.setEnabled(false);
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: venue_btn.setClickable() ?

Answer (score 1):

use `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);` method while starting activity with request code of the button clicked. and on your second activity when you are returning back just set `setResult(RESULT_OK);` which means every thing was fine in second activity and again on first activity you will get result in a call back method

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

So you can disable the button in this method by checking request code.

Hope this helps you

**EDIT:**

first take five constants like

```
private final int VENUE_BUTTON_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
```

in your click listener

```
venue_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                   Intent venue_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VenueActivity.class);
                    venue_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivityForResult(venue_intent,VENUE_BUTTON_REQUEST_CODE);

                }


            });
```

and in your callback method do like this

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if(requestCode == VENUE_BUTTON_REQUEST_CODE){
     venue_btn.setEnable(false);
      }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: Its not disabling my button :(

Comment: could you please show me some code so I can figure out problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24492/discussion-between-abhinav-singh-maurya-and-deepthi)

Comment: Abhinav Singh Maurya : I'm in chat.. Please do help :(

Comment: please come in chat if possible I was AFK

Comment: thanks a lot for your time the issue is resolved.. :) I just edited my code and it now works fine :)

Comment: So using what solution. I am egar to know that

Answer (score 0):

Well there is an easy solution you can try

When user click on button you can make entry into shared-preference notifying which button user has clicked.

for eg

```
food_cost_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.i("In Food Button isBtnVenueClikced ", isBtnVenueClikced + "");

        context.getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putBoolean("food_cost_btn", true).commit();

        Intent food_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FoodAndBeveragesActivity.class);
        food_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(food_intent);

    }
});
```

And inside onResume you will write following.

```
if (context.getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)).getBoolean("food_cost_btn", false)) {
    food_cost_btn.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: But if the user clicks button and in the activity in which the user is leads to , the user clicks the back button then the button would remain inactive right?

Comment: Yes it will! thats a purpose behind using sharedpreference.You have to make sure you perform preference checking in onResume().

Comment: hi Vipul Shah : I'm getting null pointer exception @ if (context.getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0).getBoolean("food_cost_btn", false))

Comment: @Deepthi you can ignore context

Comment: now the button remains disabled forever and is not at all enabled even if next time the user uses the app :(

Answer (score 0):

Take all 5 buttons in a array like this

```
Buttons[] buttons={venu_btn,foodcost_btn,accomadation_btn,guest_detail_btn,misc_btn};
```

now in all onclick listeners you are doing the common task so let us reduce the code first...

for the take another array

```
Class[] classes={VenueActivity.class,FoodAndBeveragesActivity.class,AccomodationActivity.class,GuestDetailsActivity.class,OthersActivity.class};
```

//set onclick Listener

```
for(int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++)
{
buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent commonintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),classes[i]);
            others_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//send selected class index that is i
             commonintent.putExtra("index",String.valueOf(i));
            startActivity( commonintent);
        }
    });
}
```

in your activity get index when return back from the activity by using string extra.. 
//you can also save them using sharedPreference but I suggest you to use intent extra

```
  String index=getIntent().getExtras().getString("index");
    if(index!=null && index.length!=null)
    {
    int i=Integer.parseInt(index);
    buttons[i].setEnable(false);
    }
```

Comment: hi Pragnani,I'm getting null pointer exception here buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {}

Comment: you need assign like this when you are getting your button objects        buttons[0] = venu_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.venu_btn); in oncreate

Comment: Still getting Null pointer Exception @ String index=getIntent().getExtras().getString("index");

Comment: get the index in onCreate and save it a global variable and and perform the required operation in onResume

Comment: make sure that you are sending and receiving the same string......also check for null before actually getting the value   example if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("details") != null)
   details = getIntent().getExtras().getString("details");

Comment: Also Its saying that a non final variable cannot be used inside inner class ,ie, inside the onClick() the variable 'i'.. May be that's a problem!!

Comment: set it final or  simply take another global variable of type int and assign i to it..and use that variable...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24545/discussion-between-pragnani-and-deepthi)

Comment: thanks a lot for your time the issue is resolved.. :) I just edited my code and it now works fine :)